# npm ERR! code EPERM and errno -4048 on windows 10

Tags: javascript, redux, npm-install, redux-form, yarnpkg

I'm writing code using WebStorm. Today I tryed to install redux-form and from that moment the code it's broken. Also if the `yarn install` goes well I i get this error into browser on localhost

```
C:/Users/WebstormProjects/.....reducer.ts
(7,40): Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-form'. 'C:/Users/WebstormProjects.....index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/redux-form` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'redux-form';`
```

The code have no semantic error and I also installed as the error says `npm install @types/redux-form` but the situation it's the same. Can someone help me??

Comment: What's on line 7 column 40 of your index.js? ;-)

Comment: @Sam The definition of the reducers, but the code it's fully working

Comment: EPERM normally has something to do with permissions. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author).*

I solved the problem deleting the directory with node modules and do: `npm install`, installing the redux-form and later installing types for this component.